# LED status for 2.5" SSD NVME

Tags: pcb, storage, ssd

I'm making a PCB for the NVME SSD connector, and I want to put a status LED on it, but I didn't find much info about it.

I found a pinout, and one of the pins is called activity (P11). I thought it would be for an LED, but it doesn't specify voltage or anything, so I don't know whether to put a resistor and an LED directly or go through a transistor first. Or is it the 3.3 V pin (E3) coming from the bus?

[image: sff-8639]

Comment: Measure it. It's likely going to be a logic level, so 3.3V is a good guess.